# How to remove compiler flag when building Boost

Tags: boost

I need to build Boost with a non-standard set of flags (due to a conflict between Boost threading and C++/CLI).  I'm adding the required flag (/clr) using CXXFLAGS, but this flag conflicts with the Boost default /EHs flag (/clr implies /EHa which is incompatible with /EHs), so that needs to be suppressed.  Is there a mechanism like CXXFLAGS to suppress a default Boost flag or must I edit all of the compiler specification files by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to remove those particular options. What you need to do is specify a specific build variant that matches what you are attempting to build. If you look at the `msvc.jam` ([see here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/tags/release/Boost_1_43_0/tools/build/v2/tools/msvc.jam)) you'll find a section where it lists the various `/EH*` options it puts in ([see here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/tags/release/Boost_1_43_0/tools/build/v2/tools/msvc.jam#L1160)). As you can see the third one matches the `/EHa` you want for C++/CLI. This translates to building with: `bjam asynch-exceptions=on extern-c-nothrow=on <rest of the args>`. The `exception-handling-on` is obviously not needed since by default you get that, and would not be seeing the `/EHs` option in the first place.