# Why do I get a Debug Assertion Failed Error when trying to execute a WinForms app that uses boost?

Tags: .net, winforms, debugging, boost, c++-cli

I am working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express.

I have created a new Windows Forms Application and added one line of code (immediately after the `#pragma once` line in Form1.h ):

```
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
```

To get this project to compile I change `/clr:pure` to `/clr`. Also, the include and library path were set to my boost build.

The application compiles, but as soon as I run it I get a Debug Assertion Failed error.

> The error occurs on File: dgbheap.c on line: 1516
>   
> at Expression: `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)`

Here is the full code for Form1.h generated by VS:

```
#pragma once

#include "boost/regex.hpp"

namespace plz {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(292, 273);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    };
}
```

I understand that an assertion failure error occurs when the assertion is false, but what is causing this? Why does this include fail when I put it in a Windows Forms application, but not in a Console application?

Thank you,
William

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? You're already using managed code, why not use the BCL's [regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)?

Comment: I'm porting code from a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Use [.NET's built-in regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) rather than Boost.Regex since you're already using managed code
2. Use [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/xpressive/index.html) rather than Boost.Regex; it's header only, so you don't run into compiler/linker config issues as you do with linked libraries
3. Non-header-only Boost libraries are linked statically by default with VC++; link to Boost.Regex dynamically rather than statically. This is described in the [Boost.Regex docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html#boost_regex.install.microsoft_visual_c___6__7__7_1_and_8) thusly: "*Note that if you want to dynamically link to the regex library when using the dynamic C++ runtime, define `BOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK` when building your project.*"
4. If you want to continue linking to Boost.Regex statically, then rebuild Boost.Regex with `/clr`; you're linking an app built with `/clr` to a static library built without it — no good. To do this, when invoking bjam, pass `asynch-exceptions=on` and `cxxflags="/clr"` as arguments

Comment: If anyone reads this and chooses option 4 check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950596/how-to-remove-compiler-flag-when-building-boost

Comment: @William Whispell : Edited to reflect the need for `asynch-exceptions=on`.

Comment: Mixing objects with and without `/clr` is perfectly fine and supported, the rest of the advice is sound.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : *Usually*, not always. Try Boost.Thread built without `/clr` statically linked to an app built with `/clr` for example.

Comment: @ildjarn: It is always supported.  It is, after all, THE recommended way to call existing C++ code from the .NET environment.  Any failures would represent bugs.  Do you have a simple repro I can upvote on Connect?

Comment: @Ben Voigt : The same bug has been open in both Boost Trac and MS Connect since Boost 1.36 was released. Neither the bug nor the fix are something new -- between here, the Boost mailing lists, and the MSDN forums, I've seen at least two dozen people report these exact symptoms, always with the same fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need a full stack trace (including module as well as function name) to know for sure, but I think you've linked with a Boost DLL which has statically linked the CRT.  That's no good, `/clr` requires using dynamic CRT (MSVCP100.DLL, IIRC).  By statically linking the CRT, boost gets its own separate heap, then some object is deallocated to a heap different from whence it came triggering this assertion.

Boost's APIs are very object-heavy and full of inline functions, so I can't imagine why anyone would ever build a Boost DLL using the static CRT.  But that's the usual explanation for this failure.